# Let's split the [atom]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request, tag-disambiguation

I keep an eye on [atom-editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/atom-editor) daily. I noticed a while ago that it is very common for [atom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/atom) to be misused as a tag on these questions. The [atom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/atom) tag is for the Atom XML syndication format, where [atom-editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/atom-editor) is for Github's Atom text editor.

This triggered my tagging OCD and a few weeks back, I went through the entire history of [atom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/atom) and read every question, looking for [atom-editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/atom-editor) questions. I didn't keep count, but I am pretty sure I retagged several dozen of them.

Since then, I watch both tags daily, and several times a week I retag from [atom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/atom) to [atom-editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/atom-editor) (and some questions simply add both). The [atom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/atom) tag excerpt already has a notice to use [atom-editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/atom-editor), but clearly people are not following the advice consistently.

I submit that [atom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/atom) has become ambiguous, and might be better renamed to something more clear. <del>My suggestions would be atom-xml or atom-format.</del> And it would only make sense to then burninate [atom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/atom).

*EDIT*: I like JeffreyBosboom's suggestion better than mine - [atom-feed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/atom-feed).

Comment: +1 to @Adriann for new title :)

Comment: Bikeshedding: how about _atom-feed_ for the syndication format?

Comment: There a 6 questions that relate to intel atom. Even though there is a tag description the tag seems to be more ambiguous than the XML parser and the editor.

Comment: Is this a symptom of a general problem of people not reading tag documentation? Could the SO UX/UI people address that? I dunno, maybe put the tag documentation in <blink> tags the first time someone tries to use one...  :)

Comment: It is back again! Somebody created this tag again 3 months ago.

Comment: @VadimKotov Yep. I re-tag numerous posts every week. Usually to atom-editor, but occasionally to atom-feed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Given that this question reached 100 votes, I went ahead and did the re-tagging over the last few days. The old tag was removed by the auto-cleaner tonight, and [atom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/atom) is gone.

Comment: It is back again! Somebody created this tag again 3 months ago.

Comment: @VadimKotov It was cleared [again](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/43019236#43019236) and is now blacklisted