# What counts as "activity" for Archaeologist?

Tags: support, badges, bug-reporting-process

In [Let's split the [atom]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/348598/2449905), I suggested we retag most [atom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/atom) questions to [atom-feed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/atom-feed). Given the positive response, I've started that process.

After I'd done a bunch of them, starting from the oldest ones, I was glancing at my profile page and I noticed Archaeologist had gone up some. That made sense, because I'd been editing a bunch of old questions (circa 2011-2013). But then it occurred to me that the increase seemed kind of low. I have at this point edited some 150+ questions, but the count on my Archaeologist tag has gone up by perhaps less than 20.

This made me wonder, what is the "activity" criteria? Most of these questions were asked and answered years ago. It seems like they haven't had activity in a long time. But the system apparently thinks many (most) of them have had activity in the past 6 months, which is the time boundary for Archaeologist.

What things count as activity for this purpose?

Comment: some of the scripts for these badges run on a low schedule, IIRC some run only every other day so if the counts are still off for 2 days then I would suspect something is broken. Until that moment we blame caching.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Activity is determined by new answers and edits to the question. The last activity date is listed on the right of the question.

However, I don't think the "activity" criterion is the problem here, but the "edit" itself.

It seems that "minor" edits do not count as edits towards some badges. And you did a lot of tag-only edits which therefore won't be counted.

This has never been officially confirmed, but there is evidence:

- [Why have I not received the archaeologist badge?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184009/164356)
- [Do tag edits count for Archaeologist?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126624/164356)

Anyway, I'd strongly recommend to edit the questions themselves too if you're retagging them, i.e. fix typos, grammar and formatting issues if there are any.