# Prevent [Atom] from ever occurring again

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request, tag-disambiguation

[atom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/atom) has resurfaced again. Now in connection to an Erlang feature.
Maybe it needs to be renamed to [erlang-atom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/erlang-atom), if it really makes sense - or burninated.

Atom is the name for:

- [Atom Feed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_(standard))
- [Text editor](https://atom.io/)
- [Erlang programming concept](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/data_types.html)
  -- this concept is called **Symbols** in LISP/Ruby
- Indivisible object in Common LISP
- Atom type in Clojure (relates to atomic operations)
- [Haskell EDSL](https://github.com/tomahawkins/atom)

After previous burnination [Atom] was also used to indicate:

- atoms of a DNS name
- atoms as text tokens in a string split
- a number of other one-off uses

(see [comment by Dan Lowe](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/360333/prevent-atom-from-ever-occurring-again/360369#comment538116_360333)

Furthermore, thanks to  @Candy Gumdrop:

> "atom" in the sense described here (note by editor: indivisible object) is only really an official term in Common LISP (not Scheme / Clojure, though some people use the term when talking about Scheme). And this meaning of "atom" (a non-"cons" data type) is completely different to the atomic tag, which is talking about atomic updates to data to avoid race conditions involving concurrency. "atom" is a type in Clojure, which relates to this meaning of "atomic". "atom" in Erlang / Elixir is actually something completely different to both of these and is just the Erlang name for what are called symbols in LISP / Ruby

As it [has been burninated before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348598/lets-split-the-atom), I suggest it should be put on the black-list.

Comment: I assume by block-list you are making a blacklist request..So changed to correct tag.

Comment: @SurajRao exactly and thanks!

Comment: It is never ambiguous, we expect questions to have more than one tag.  There is no overlap in these topics.  Also the basic way that common tags like [exception], [performance], etc work.  Stop burninating it to get ahead.

Comment: @HansPassant so I guess the Tag Wiki should describe all possible uses?

Comment: @HansPassant note: I don't think that would be necessary for [exception] and [performance] because these are concepts which have a specific meaning which don't really depend on context (other than programming...). With [atom] that is not the case.

Comment: @HansPassant `It is never ambiguous.`  It is *absolutely* ambiguous.  That much is evident from the four completely unrelated meanings listed in the post.

Comment: As noted in the linked question, I burninated [atom] back in May. It was clean for a while, but it resurfaced several weeks later. I noticed it early on and retagged the handful of posts that had it, and it's been clean since (until now). But just to note - this is the second time it's resurfacing since the May burnination.

Comment: I'll also mention that these are not the only four things people have used the tag for. During burnination, I found mostly Atom Editor posts and Atom Feed, some Erlang and Haskell, but there were also posts which referred to the atoms of a DNS name, atoms as text tokens in a string split, and a number of other one-off uses. I agree with the OP, it's generic enough to warrant blacklisting.

Comment: In addition to the listed items, Atom is also a name of an Intel line of processors. And even more commonly, _atomic_ is an important concept in computing, referring to objects that can get accesses in a single instruction. There is a tag [tag:atomic] but I can see how people might mix up the similar sounding tags.

Comment: Can I get a community feel for posting a socratic-style community wiki answer as opposed to continually revising my own answer?

Comment: Title suggestion: Prevent [Atom] from becoming a molecule

Comment: FYI, I've been tidying up [atom] again, numerous [atom-editor] questions are still being tagged as [atom]. I cleaned up within the last 48 hours or so, and since then there are another 4 of them I'm about to clean up now.

Comment: I removed the blacklist tag from this post, as there's a newer one by @DanLowe asking for it to be blacklisted https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364668/time-to-smash-the-atom-permanently?noredirect=1&lq=1. There are no remaining questions in atom, now

Answer (score 11):

If it's not to be burninated... then we definitely need to disambiguate it. I'd suggest having `atom-feed` or `atom-xml` refer to the atom feed (as `atom-feed` already does,) `atom-editor` refer to the atom editor, `haskell-atom` refer to the haskell concept, and `atom` refer to the general programming idea of an indivisible object.

While the first three definitions are rather niche concepts, which are unlikely to appear (Note: unlikely. Not impossible,) the fourth definition is, IMHO, essential to LISPlike languages. Given that the LISP documentation has two basic types (`atoms` and `lists`, which themselves are made of `atoms`), I would suggest we build a disambiguated programming representation of `atom`. Maybe...

- `atom-programming`? This would need to be rectified as soon as some genius makes an esoteric programming language named 'atom'. Also, it could be confused with programming inside the text editor.
- `atom`? Ok, I know this has been burninated before, but consider adding a blurb inside the help tooltip describing that this tag is *not* for the other three (Or more, as they accumulate) definitions of atom, it's simply for the programming concept.
- `atom-concept`? This could be wrong in terms of connotation: it naturally lends itself to people looking to figure out what atoms are, not people having issues with atoms while programming.
- `atom-indivisible`? This concisely describes the programming concept while excluding the other three definitions.

If it *is* to be burninated... then something needs to take its place. As I've outlined above, it's a basic tenet of LISPlike programming. Given that at least four different languages (LISP, clojure, scheme, and, apparently Erlang) have atoms, it's not simply something that can be substructured under a language tag. We need a tag to describe the concept.

UPDATE:

Apparently, there is already a tag for this concept, `atomic`. I suggest we fold the LISP definition into it.

Note that I am by no means an expert in the topic, nor do I have much experience with the way that SE sites in general phrase their tagging.

### Final Recommendation:

1. Burninate `atom`. It's too ambiguous.
2. Make `atom-xml` a synonym for `atom-feed`.
3. Use `atom-editor` (and/or maybe `atom-text-editor`) for the text editor.
4. Create `haskell-atom` for the haskell EDSL.
5. Fold the lisp definition of an atom into the `atomic` tag. Maybe create a `atom-indivisible` synonym to it? Or would that clutter things up?

Comment: The tag wiki is not sufficient. The old tag wiki already said not to use it for the Atom text editor, but dozens of posts did anyway. (The original tag was for the XML format.)

Comment: I apologize for sounding like a total noob, but where is this tag wiki, anyways?

Comment: @JakobLovern https://stackoverflow.com/tags/atom/info It's what you get when you click "Learn more..." when you are looking at all questions from a particular tag.

Comment: @JakobLovern, I think the programming concept should use the currently-existing `atomic` tag.

Comment: [tag:atom-feed] already exists.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom Yeah, I learned that after posting this. I'll modify my answer to accommodate the `atomic` tag and the `atom-feed` tag, now.

Comment: @NH. The `atomic` tag is a useful one to know, but it does not cover the way `atom` is used by Erlang (a data type). It might cover the Haskell usage, based on my 30 seconds of reading about it.

Comment: @DanLowe I'm looking to add the Erlang definition to the `atomic` tag.

Comment: @JakobLovern [tag:atom-editor] exists too and has more than 2000 questions.

Comment: Tag wikis (rather than excerpts) are basically invisible to most users. As far as I can tell, they're completely unreachable on mobile. Until that UI is given a major overhaul, it might as well not exist.

Comment: "atom" in the sense described here is only really an official term in Common LISP (not Scheme / Clojure, though some people use the term when talking about Scheme).  And this meaning of "atom" (a non-"cons" data type) is completely different to the [tag:atomic] tag, which is talking about atomic updates to data to avoid race conditions involving concurrency.  "atom" is a type in Clojure, which relates to this meaning of "atomic".  "atom" in Erlang / Elixir is actually something completely different to both of these and is just the Erlang name for what are called symbols in LISP / Ruby.

Comment: Well then... Looks like I've done insufficient research. So be it, I've posted my main concerns. I'll update them (_again_) with this new info. Also, @CandyGumdrop, would you mind editing the question to include these definitions? I feel like it would help anybody else wishing to weigh input.

Comment: So... Have we reached a consensus on this, yet?

Comment: @JakobLovern Not sure. The pro-votes on this answer have increased far less than on the question - where I suggested black listing. Thus I just offered a [counter proposal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/360817/684096) for burnination. Don't know whether this makes sense as probably loads of people will not look at this post again and vote again. Hence, lesson learned: i should always provide (at least) two answer along with the question, one pro one con ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Suggestion:

- Burninate [Atom]
- Blacklist [Atom]
- Let the community handle the creation of any non-ambiguous "atom"-related tags like [Erlang-Atom] (on a "as needed" basis).
- Note: [atom-editor], [atom-feed] already exist.

Reasoning:

- Tag keeps reappearing again
- many different meanings - very ambiguous
- see comments by Dan Lowe: [1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/360333/prevent-atom-from-ever-occurring-again/360817#comment538115_360333) [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/360333/prevent-atom-from-ever-occurring-again/360817#comment538116_360333)