# Time to smash the [atom] permanently

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-disambiguation, blocklist-request

The [atom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/atom) tag has resurfaced again.

I first [proposed burnination](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348598/lets-split-the-atom) in April 2017, and I did a mass re-tag when the post reached a score of 100.

For a while, [atom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/atom) was gone, but it resurfaced after a short time, as was discussed in [BatteryBackupUnit's post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/360333/prevent-atom-from-ever-occurring-again) from December 2017.

I have been monitoring this tag almost daily for months, and it is regularly misused. I just went through my revision history and tallied it up for 2018 year-to-date. Here are the totals I found. I don't believe I am the only one fixing tagging on this, so this likely under-represents the problem.

- changed [atom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/atom) to [atom-editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/atom-editor): 54
- changed [atom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/atom) to [atom-feed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/atom-feed): 1
- removed [atom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/atom) because [atom-editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/atom-editor) was already tagged: 8
- removed [atom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/atom) because [atom-feed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/atom-feed) was already tagged: 1

So I put my edit total at 64 so far this year, 74 days into the year (meaning I've edited one post per day on average, 86% of the year to date).

It seems clear that this tag is going to keep surviving burnination, as people continue to use it incorrectly, whether [atom-editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/atom-editor) is tagged already or not.

(At this moment time, only 4 posts are tagged [atom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/atom).)

Comment: Your question title has been awarded the Meta Stamp Of Approval℠ by the Stack Overflow Punny Title Commission. Well done!

Comment: I have to say, seeing SO users constantly re-activate the worst damn questions definitely makes my front page worse.  Just let SO users correct tags on the ones that actually matter.  Stop worrying and love the [atom] bomb.

Comment: I've retagged like 10-15 questions with proper tags too

Comment: To put Hans comment into context: the likeness of seeing any of these edited questions in the home page (/) is directly proportional to the combinations of tags that these questions have that you have answered before, inversely proportional to the amount of activity in any of these tags, inversely proportional to the activity that questions that use tags which questions you have answered before, inversely proportional to the amount of questions to be edited answered before and inversely proportional to the amount of questions edited that already have answers.

Comment: TL;dr: is *extremely unlikely* that anyone that have never answered any atom* tag to see any of those questions in the homepage.

Comment: I think we can create something like [tag:atom-data-type] for Erlang/Elixir

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now blacklisted:

[image: Please use a less ambiguous tag: atom-editor: that GitHub / Electron thing; atom-feed: he XML standard that's better than RSS; atomicity: the quality of indivisibility]

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps we should just explicitly let people know to avoid it by editing it into the tag use guidelines.

It currently  reads "An atom is a constant whose name is its own value. Some other languages call these symbols" which in my opinion is vague and in no way conveys any relation to atom.io, nor did I find any reference to symbols or constants being called atoms at atom.io.

I would suggest, and this is the point of this answer, to change the text to

> PLEASE DO NOT USE THIS TAG. It has been [removed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/348598/1026459) [twice](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/360333/1026459) already and this guidance comes from a [third](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/364668/1026459) discussion. This tag is overly vague and does not fit with the quality standards of Stack Overflow.

Comment: +1 for synonym.  Considering `atom` *is* the name of the app, it seems reasonable that people would want to use that tag.

Comment: If the objective is to not use this tag anymore, I see no reason to be allowed to be used.

Comment: Back when we originally burninated the tag, it did say to not use it, and people were using it anyway. People don't read that, unfortunately.

Comment: @Gimby - Yes, that is a good point. Clearly an oversight on my part, perhaps I should just remove that part.

Comment: People don't read tag descriptions - "DO NOT USE" descriptions don't really help much. We should just blacklist it.

Comment: @EJoshuaS - I am fine with blacklisting it, but from a community standpoint all we can do at this point without a CM is to edit the tag wiki.