# This tag needs a re-[mix]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

The [mix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mix) tag is supposed to be about [a tool for the Elixir language](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/mix-otp/introduction-to-mix.html) but it is constantly being misused in questions about [Laravel Mix](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/) which should have the [laravel-mix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel-mix) tag.

Given that the correct usage of the tag is so light (292 questions total) I suggest the tag should be renamed **elixir-mix** to avoid this confusion, and the original burninated. I corrected dozens of mistagged questions a few weeks back but obviously they will keep coming back.

Comment: All questions (apart from maybe 3) are about elixir. Why is this a burnination request and not a rename request?

Comment: @Tomerikoo because some users believe that any tag removal is a burnination, despite the fact that the number of tags at the end of day will either stay equal or be higher. So, yeah.

Comment: @Tomerikoo because I assume if the `mix` tag is left, it will continue to be used for Laravel Mix questions. I suppose it could be synonymized with `laravel-mix`? Sorry for not being clear on all the terminology, I was using [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348598/lets-split-the-atom) as a guide.

Comment: Also @Tomerikoo all the questions are about Elixir because I removed the tag from dozens of questions about Laravel Mix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I went through the set of questions with [mix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mix), but without [elixir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/elixir), and all of them were related to Elixir. So I renamed the tag [mix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mix) to [elixir-mix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/elixir-mix).

Now, for the tag [mix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mix) itself, I did not add it as a synonym to [elixir-mix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/elixir-mix), as the laravel one seemed to be used more frequently. I usually try to synonymize an ambiguous tag to something in order to prevent it from being recreated, but decided to *mix* up things a bit here. Let us revisit the tag if it is recreated and later on decide whether to synonymize it or not.

Comment: We should not synonymize it in any case; it is ambiguous and should be burninated entirely.